# how do i concatenate two different files into one file using python

Tags: python-2.7

**input:** I have more than 100 sample files. Each sample file  has two different files has an extension of `*.column' and *.datatypes`

**File1** each file has `column` names  and has an extension of *.column
 `datatypes` description and has an extension of *.datatypes

What I need is an `output` file  in their respective files sample
**Output File** should have `column` names along with `datatypes`.

Currently am getting all 100 files data merged and saved into one file.
Eg: file_1:

```
column names   datatypes
id             int
name           string
```

Eg: file_2:

```
column names   datatypes
id             int
name           string
```

i got the output for all files column names and datatypes merged in one **single** file.
What I need is to get **individual** files merged separately for each sample.

```
for name in os.listdir("C:\Python27"):
if name.endswith(".column"):
    for file in name:
        file = os.path.join(name)
        joined = file+ ".joined"
        with open(joined,"w") as fout:
            filenames = glob.glob('*.column')
            for filename in filenames:
                with open(filename) as f1:
                    file_names = glob.glob('*.datatypes')
                    for filename in file_names:
                        with open(filename) as f2:
                            for line1,line2 in zip(f1,f2):
                                x = ("{0} {1} \n".format(line1.rstrip(),line2.rstrip()))
                                y = x.strip()
                                fout.write(y.strip() + ',\n')
```

Please assist me.

Comment: Is this resolved? If not what is difference between `filename.column` and `filename.col`

Comment: No still am facing the issue.

Comment: Can you give output from `dir C:\Python27`??

Comment: Are you running this from `C:\Python27` or from a different folder?

Comment: Thanks for editing the source as `.col` and `.column` created a confusion of existence of three types of input files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully the below would work. This is on the understanding that each `*.column` file has a corresponding `*.datatypes` file name, if not the code will throw a `File not found.` error.

```
for colname in os.listdir("C:\Python27"):
    if colname.endswith(".column"):
            print('Processing:' + colname)
            file = os.path.splitext(colname)[0]
            joined = file+ ".joined"
            with open(joined,"w") as fout:
                with open(colname) as f1:
                    datname = file+'.datatypes'
                    with open(datname) as f2:
                        for line1,line2 in zip(f1,f2):
                            x = ("{0} {1}".format(line1.rstrip(),line2.rstrip()))
                            y = x.strip()
                            fout.write(y.strip() + ',\n')
                        print('Finished writing to :'+joined)
```

I test ran this with a few sample input files as below
 [file1.column](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz4r9OFqWuTxR2RrY09JbnAyVms)

```
date_sev
pos
```

[file1.datatypes](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz4r9OFqWuTxSWFvQU5FZHYxYVU)

```
timestamp
date
```

[file2.column](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz4r9OFqWuTxSEFVcVlvYm84dDg)

```
id
name
```

[file2.datatypes](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz4r9OFqWuTxTGdBOWY2REdCZ3c)

```
int
string
```

[file3.column](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz4r9OFqWuTxOEU1dDVIeWtWZ1U)

```
id
name
```

[file3.datatypes](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz4r9OFqWuTxYmdPajdjQ3VsY0k)

```
int
string
```

When I run the file I get the below output in the console

```
Processing:file1.column
Finished writing to :file1.joined
Processing:file2.column
Finished writing to :file2.joined
Processing:file3.column
Finished writing to :file3.joined
```

And the output files I get are
 [file1.joined](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz4r9OFqWuTxajNWYmRNdDBlODg)

```
date_sev timestamp,
pos date,
```

[file2.joined](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz4r9OFqWuTxZWRBTklRNUhSeWM)

```
id int,
name string,
```

[file3.joined](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz4r9OFqWuTxNkw3cm0wZkpoZXc)

```
id int,
name string,
```

Also if you want to better the output syntax of the files then I would make the changes as below...
**From**

```
x = ("{0} {1}".format(line1.rstrip(),line2.rstrip()))
```

**To**

```
x = ("{0},{1}".format(line1.rstrip(),line2.rstrip()))
```

**From**

```
fout.write(y.strip() + ',\n')
```

**To**

```
fout.write(y.strip() + '\n')
```

I left the formatting as is from your initial version in my original solution posted in the beginning.

Comment: Does the above work for you? Hope the above clarifies the logic a bit. Let me know if you've any questions. Otherwise mark the question as answered.

Comment: No it didn't work for me. Because .column file having only column names and .datatypes having only datatypes i want both to be in file for each individual files.

Comment: Doesn't the above code generate as many `.joined` files as there are `.column`+`.datatypes` files??

Comment: Your initial version of code generated all the `.joined` files but all of them would have **all** the `.column` & `.datatypes`data in them making them identical.

Comment: Can you show output for `dir ABC.*`.   `ABC` being one of the table names which has `.column` and `.datatypes` files?

Comment: eg:File3: '.column' file having date_sev,pos

Comment: and '.datatypes' file having timestamp,date

Comment: Made a minor edit to code with two print statements. Can you post the output??

Comment: posted the code doesn't gave any output. I posted the code giving the output like combining all files (file1,file2,file3,and so on) and giving into each file .

Comment: Can you give me the output from your windows CMD for `dir file3.*`?

Comment: Do you see `file3.joined`? If so does it have any data in it?

Comment: file3:'.joined' output is id  int,name  string,id  int,name  string,date_sev timestamp, pos date, and so on.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted??

Comment: That should correspond to merging **only** `file3.column` and `file3.datatypes`.

Comment: yes but along with file1 and file2 also coming i want alone individual files

Comment: Can you give me output for `dir file3.*`?

Comment: Run that from where you are running the python script.

Comment: I just ran the above python script and it produces proper files. I suggest you run this command after running the command  `del *.joined` **Be very careful this will delete all the .joined files**

Comment: I just updated my answer with all the files I ran and the output I get. Try and see if you can get the same output.

Comment: Let me know the output you are getting after the cleanup.

Comment: If nothing works I would suggest creating a separate folder and copying 3 files into it and running it afresh.